# how to fix "Can't resolve all parameters for DynamicDatabase: (?)."

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Im trying to add a component to my project - "tree dynamic example"
you can see it here:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/eaaramngjoqq?file=app%2Ftree-dynamic-example.ts

right now if you go to this site and add a new service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NewService {

  constructor() { }

}
```

and then go to tree-dynamic-example.ts and add this line 
(constructor(private newService: NewService){}
) like this:

```
export class DynamicDatabase {

constructor(private newService: NewService){}

dataMap = new Map<string, string[]>([
    ['Fruits', ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana']],
    ['Vegetables', ['Tomato', 'Potato', 'Onion']],
    ['Apple', ['Fuji', 'Macintosh']],
    ['Onion', ['Yellow', 'White', 'Purple']]
  ]);
```

it will tell you:
Can't resolve all parameters for DynamicDatabase: (?).

I checked the questions about this subject, and they didn't help - 
I didn't forget to write @ or () in the @injectable() 
I added the app.module.ts this line in my project:

```
@NgModule
.
.
providers: [NewService]
```

but I keep getting this error.

p.s. I'm kinda new to angular so maybe I forgot something basic, will appreciate the help

Comment: Did you import your service into `tree-dynamic-example.ts` by doing `import { NewService } from 'path/to/service'`?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this problem is directly connected with that you try to inject service into class meanwhile it's supposed to be injected into component or directive. It works if you place it in class with decorator https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a6m76r?file=app/tree-dynamic-example.ts

However, if you need to have a service inside a plain class you may instantiate your service by hand (check `ser` in first class). When you use `constructor(private service: Service)` Angular creates an instance of that service for you (or uses global one if you use `@Injectable({provideIn:'root'})`.

Service is just a class with decorator that helps Angular to resolve DI (Dependency Injection). Thus using in class it requires you to create an instance of that serivce by hand unless you want to use static methods.

---

### TL;DR;

**1 case** - you need you service in a component

```
@Component(...)
export class Component {
  constructor (private service: Service) }
}
```

Angular creates an instance of a service for you via DI.

**2 case** - you want to use service in a class

```
export class BaseClass {
  private service;

  constructor() {
    this.service = new Service();
  }
}
```

There is no decorators so Angular is unable to resolve DI for us, therefore we create an instance of a service in constructor(like we would working with a traditional class which service actually is).